# Changed Events are not firing in Couchbase Lite Replication

Tags: c#, xamarin, couchbase, couchbase-lite

As the title mentions, I'm trying to write some tests around my custom conflict resolution engine, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting couchbase replication to play ball.

```
[Test]
public async Task TestSyncReplicationAsync()
{
    bool replicationAttempted = false;
    bool replicationSuccess = false;
    _secondPull.Changed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case ReplicationStatus.Idle:
                replicationSuccess = CheckDocumentReplicatedToSecondDatabase();
                replicationAttempted = true;
                break;
            case ReplicationStatus.Active:
                var a = 1;
                break;
            case ReplicationStatus.Offline:
                var b = 2;
                break;
            case ReplicationStatus.Stopped:
                var c = 3;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    var freshDoc = _firstDb.GetDocument(_testRecordId);
    freshDoc.PutProperties(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        {"name", "Phil"},
        {"age", "40"},
        {"type", "person"}
    });

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!replicationAttempted)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Spinning waiting for pull");
        }
    });

    Assert.True(replicationSuccess, "Record was not replicated successfully");
}
```

The replications work, but I'm duping sync by running two buckets within one simulator, so simply put, create a record in the first bucket, wait for the second replication object, `_secondPull`'s state to change then evaluate if it's got the new record.

This is the first and most basic of the tests I'm running, but even though the record does sync. Changed event is not firing and therefore I can't complete my test?  The asynchronous while loop is just to keep the test code alive.  I've had mixed success with having a direct:

```
while(_firstPush.Status == ReplicationStatus.Active)
{
    //DoNothing
}

while(_secondPull.Status == ReplicationStatus.Active)
{
    //DoNothing
}

///CarryOnTest
```

However this doesn't give repeated success and it's ugly af. Sometimes the debugger just spins indefinitely, other times it just gets stuck and kills VS2013.

I don't believe I'm missing anything but sadly the CB documentation is lacking...

Answer (score 0):

It's bit unclear how you hook-up your eventhandler to the "Changed" event. If you are using to separate instances of Couchbase Lite you need to make sure that you subscribe to the right instance of Couchbase Lite for the changes.

Can you share the code where you subscribe to the changed event?

UPDATE: Here is a code snippet that replicates documents from one CB Lite instance to another, in the same app. In this case a WPF app.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        var cb1 = Manager.SharedInstance.GetDatabase("cb1");
        cb1.Changed += Cb1_Changed;

        var cb2 = Manager.SharedInstance.GetDatabase("cb2");
        cb2.Changed += Cb2_Changed;

        string url = "http://try-cb.cloudapp.net:4984/sync_gateway/";
        var auth = new Couchbase.Lite.Auth.BasicAuthenticator("couchbase", "letmein");

        var push = cb1.CreatePushReplication(new Uri(url));
        push.Continuous = true;
        push.Authenticator = auth;
        push.Start();

        var pull = cb2.CreatePullReplication(new Uri(url));
        pull.Continuous = true;
        pull.Authenticator = auth;
        pull.Start();

    }

    private void Cb2_Changed(object sender, DatabaseChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb2 = Manager.SharedInstance.GetDatabase("cb2");
        var docs = e.Changes
            .Select(id => cb2.GetDocument(id.DocumentId))
            .ToList();

        Debugger.Break();
    }

    private void Cb1_Changed(object sender, DatabaseChangeEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb1 = Manager.SharedInstance.GetDatabase("cb1");

        var doc = cb1.CreateDocument();
        var props = doc.UserProperties != null ? doc.Properties : new Dictionary<string, object>();
        props["doc"] = new
        {
            type = "test",
            guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        doc.PutProperties(props);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, it's right there in my first sample.  It's an anonymous event handler body.  I've tried with a method reference as well and it was no different.